# Where should I write the code for SMS API integration in WordPress website?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, integration

I'm using WordPress and I want to integrate an SMS API into my WordPress site. When a new user registers on the site a welcome SMS should be sent and after approval the approval SMS should be sent automatically.

I'm using ultimate plugin in WordPress. Where (in which file) should I write the code for integration and also the code to integrate SMS API?

Here is my API URL:

`http://login.bulksmsservice.net.in/api/mt/SendSMS?user=xxxxxx&password=xxxxxxxx&senderid=xxxx&channel=xxx=0&flashsms=0&number=xxxxxxxx&text=xxx&route=xx`

Answer (score 0):

I can't give a full answer but this should be a [plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin).
In this plugin you can register the hook [user_register](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register)

Hope this helps you get started.

Comment: thanks for quick response  but there is no plugins and i am using ultimate member plugis

Comment: I'm suggesting you have to create your own plugin.